# Trying to create CMainFrame with pRuntimeClass::CreateObject()

Tags: c++, mfc

As title said, I'm trying to create CMainFrame without using new CMainFrame;
I figured how to create CMainFrame with RuntimeClass but after few debugging process I just found pFrame is not valid.

at line (!pFrame), pFrame is 0x00000000{CMainFrame hWnd = ???}
unlikely pFrame is being 0xwhatever{CMainFrame HWnd = 0x00000000} when I'm using (new)

```
CRuntimeClass* pRuntimeClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame); 
CMainFrame* pFrame = (CMainFrame*)pRuntimeClass->CreateObject();
// pFrame = new CMainFrame;

if (!pFrame)
    return FALSE;
```

any clue to solve this problem?
I'm pretty new at mfc stuffs.

Comment: Should not be possible that pFrame gets NULL just in between those two statements. Sure that you don't debug release code?

Comment: If you are new to MFC I suggest using the default method to create the frame window instead of trying to roll your own.